# Eclipse Hot Code Swap

Tags: html, css, eclipse, jsp, browser

So I'm developing a Spring MVC style web application and previously I had been able to do 'hot code' swaps where I could modify my HTML, CSS, XML and save it inside of Eclipse and it would update itself in the browser with a page refresh.

Fast forward a few months I had a comp crash but I had backups of my project/eclipse/workspace and now the hot swaps no longer work and at some points it even gets to the point where complete redeploys wont provide the visual updates(CSS, HTML) without clearing my browser cache but the backend(JAVA) will still update each time without fail.

So does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

Additional details -> when I goto examine elements(in chrome) the updates don't appear and my css file that I can open from that interface doesn't have the updates inside of it until I clear the cache and redeploy the project.

-> I'm using Eclipse EE as my IDE

Comment: delete your browser cache and check

Comment: @RameshK Still didn't work I think the issue may lie solely in Eclipse because before when I had made a change and saved it appeared like the code had been recomipiling and attempting a redeploy but now it doesn't do that anymore.

Comment: there is a option build automatically, under project tab.